# what's the best media solution for java in a chat application?

Tags: java, audio, media, flash-media-server, jmf

I'm about to make a decision about the ideal technology for audio/video chat and I need your expert advice, specifically on the client side.

java media framework doesn't seem mature enough,
fms seems ok but are there any java clients for flash media server or Red5?

any clues, guides appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick with JMF. We have exhaustively researched the alternatives at my company and its prob the best thing out there. Sure, you could use FMJ, but for security reasons, we stayed away from open source. The unfortunate truth is that you really don't have to many options.